# What can i use instead of 'for' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a very beginner question.

First of all, i have an Entity(Person) with an Attribute(name).

I want to fetch the name attributes to one array to pick a randomElement from. The following code successfully returns data to separate arrays:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var myArray: [String]?

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

            if let username = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
                myArray = [username]
                print(myArray!)
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("not successful")
    }
```

What can I use instead of '**FOR**'? And how?

Thank you so much, and sorry for my soo beginner question.

Comment: Your code leaves `myArray` with a single username - the last one.

Comment: What is your actual question? Why don't you want to use `for`? What is your goal for using something else?

Comment: Use myarray= results.map{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may cast to actual entity name

```
var myArray = [String]()

do {
       let results = try context.fetch(request)
       myArray  = (results as! [Person]).compactMap { $0.name }  
       print(myArray) 
}
catch {
    print("not successful")
}
```